# Creating S/MIME from MIME?

Tags: php, openssl, smime, mime-message

I don't completely understand and some documentation or help would be appreciated greatly :)

Using PHP I create a MIME by using ezcomponents Mail object. But what I do not understand is:

Do you create an S/MIME message from a original MIME by signing it with [openssl_pkcs7_sign](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php) ? or do you create an S/MIME from scratch and sign it when its done?

Please bear with me as I try to understand the correct way of doing things.

**EDIT**: Found this piece of code to illustrate my question better

```
<?
// Setup mail headers.
$headers = array("To" => "someone@nowhere.net",
     "From" => "noone@somewhere.net",
     "Subject" => "A signed and encrypted message.");

// Sign the message first
openssl_pkcs7_sign("msg.txt","signed.txt",
     "signing_cert.pem",array("private_key.pem",
     "password"),array());

// Get the public key certificate.
$pubkey = file_get_contents("cert.pem");

//encrypt the message, now put in the headers.
openssl_pkcs7_encrypt("signed.txt", "enc.txt",
     $pubkey,$headers,0,1);

$data = file_get_contents("enc.txt");

// separate header and body, to use with mail function
//  unfortunate but required, else we have two sets of headers
//  and the email client doesn't decode the attachment
$parts = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);

// send mail (headers in the Headers parameter will override those
//  generated for the To & Subject parameters)
mail($mail, $subject, $parts[1], $parts[0]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of pain and route the messages you need signed through a MTA filter that is designed for the job, e.g. [Gnu Anubis](ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.gnu.org/software/anubis/manual/anubis.html#SEC63) (SMTP proxy) or implement a milter

Comment: The thing is I want to let my users programatically create their own signatures and select an option in my application to send as secure or not.

Comment: "Anubis version 4.1 does not yet provide built-in support for S/MIME encryption or signing" That will not do my friend. I do not want to use external stuff all the time because of the configuration gremlins that exist. I'd rather then do it myself using PHP

Comment: Neither does PHP - the difference is that Anubis is specifically designed for the prupose of modifying email content - of course if you're a far superior programmer to the guys who wrote anubis then you've nothing to worry about - but if that's the case then why are you asking us how to implement this?

Comment: hehe because I am not nearly that good of a programmer, thats why I asked.

Comment: Can you walk me through how Anubis would be implemented in this case? Please? This is the best way +1